# JSLint warnings

Tags: javascript, jslint

I cannot figure out why JSlint is giving the following warnings:

1. Unexpected 'this'
2. Expected ';' and instead saw 'capWord'
3. Expected ';' and instead saw 'i'
4. Stopping

Here is the code : It runs without any errors. I just want to make it JSLint compliant.

```
"use strict";

function capWord(inStr) {
   this.inStr = inStr; //Unexpected 'this'
}

capWord.firstIndex = function(inStr) {
   document.write(this.upper(inStr[0])); //Unexpected 'this'
   this.space(inStr); //Unexpected 'this'
}

capWord.space = function(inStr) {
   for(var i=1;i<inStr.length;i=i+1) { //Unexpected 'for'; Expected ';' and instead saw 'i'
   document.write(inStr[i]);
   if (inStr[i] == " ") {
        document.write(this.upper(inStr[i+1]));
        i = i+1;
    }
  }
}

capWord.upper = function(charUpper) {
   return charUpper.toUpperCase();
}

capWord.firstIndex("lfadjadjfkaru wish this wouldnt be hapeingig");
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicate in which lines the warnings occur and including all your code. However since not all your code is here I'm betting on a missing brace or something like that

Comment: better yet...put a comment with the error on appropriate lines. Does the code throw errors when run? If not this really shouldn't even be a question

Comment: Just read the error messages. It says `Expected ';' and instead saw 'capWord'`. That's because your assignment statement ending on line 9, among others, does not have a semi-colon at the end. Also, what is `inStr = inStr` supposed to do? You will also need to arrange to have `document` not throw a not defined error.

Comment: @torazaburo My explanation was incorrect, I should have tried the fix before I posted it. But just so you can reproduce the `this` error, try pasting OP's code here: http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: you could format your code in [jspretty](http://www.jspretty.com/) and use [Jslint options](http://jshint.com/docs/options/) appended to the top of the file to ignore some cases.

Comment: @charlietfl I have added information to my post as per your recommendation.  Thanks. Also, this code runs correctly. I am just trying to make it JSLint compliant.

Comment: Crockford doesn't use `this` anymore, and if you look at the [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) site, you'll see that __tolerate: this__ is now an option you have to set explicitly.

Comment: @torazaburo Can you point out which statement you are talking about? I do not see any code that is not ending appropriately with a semicolon. There is no assignment statement on line 9.

Comment: The statements of the form `capWord.firstIndex = function() {...}` are assignments which need to end with a semi-colon. Line 9 is the end of that assignment statement and needs a semi-colon after the right curly bracket.

Comment: The quickest way to avoid `this` is to use a (revealing) module instead of a constructor so that everything you need is in-scope.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that Crockford doesn't recommend using the `this` keyword. I have tried to limit its usage as much as possible. Is there a replacement of `this` that I can use (e.g. Is there a way to call the space function without using the `this` keyword)